# Why is launching JupyterLab from my python2.7 anaconda environment failing with a syntaz error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter

First, I'm new to anaconda (3.9) and jupyerlab.

When I launch jupyterlab from my python 3.10.8 environment in the anaconda navigator it works fine
But when I launch it from my python 2.7.18 environment it throws the error below.

EDIT for clarification: I won't be writing code in Py2, but I'm fairly sure I may come across Py2 dependencies at some point so was just setting up an environment for that possibility. Like I said I'm new to anaconda and jupyter - so just exploring for now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in 
from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 31, in 
from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 15, in 
from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in 
from .application import *
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 17, in 
from decorator import decorator
File "/home/bioinfguru/anaconda3/envs/python2718/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 162
print('Error in generated code:', file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried:

1. Adding another kernel to jupyterlab but it isn't very intuitive and as I'm new to this I'm not sure I won't be messing up my jupyterlab.
2. Parsing the error I noticed all calls print the format "line X, in
   from Y File". The last call only prints "line X". Not sure what to do with that.
3. When opening the environment in the terminal it confirms Im using python2.7.18

   ```
    bioinfguru@bioinfguru-Legion-5-15IAH7H:~$ python -V
   ```

   Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: `print` isn't a function in Python2, so `print(something, file=something_else)` is invalid syntax. In general, modern Python3 is unlikely to run without modification under Python2.

Comment: You really shouldn't use Python 2.7 anymore. 3.x might directly solve the syntax error there.

Comment: @MattDMo print(something), yes; print(something, **kwargs), no

Comment: @snakecharmerb you're right, forgot about that. It's been a while....

Comment: @MattDMo tho the future import for print would fix this particular case.

Comment: It looks like the current version of [`decorator`](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) only supports Python 3.5+. Not sure when Py2 support was dropped, but it was likely a while ago.

Comment: @MattDMo Decorator not supporting Py2 seems to be the most plausible answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MattDMo

"It looks like the current version of decorator only supports Python 3.5+. Not sure when Py2 support was dropped, but it was likely a while ago."

I see how you got there. Next time I'll check the project docs for supported languages